# JavaDoc for private / protected methods?

Tags: java, javadoc, private, protected

Should I write JavaDoc for *private* or *protected* methods? And what about *private* variables?

I see class examples on my Java book and the *private* variables are JavaDoc'ed.
So I can't understand if it is a good practice to JavaDoc the *private* (or *protected*) methods.

Comment: You should write comments for anything that isn't obvious.

Comment: In your javadocs on private/protected methods will show up if you use the show javadocs command in your IDE (at least Intellij). In line comments will not. That's one practical benefit to javadocs instead of inline comments when description beyond the method signature is useful.

Answer (score 72):

Yes you should write JavaDoc for private methods, and even when it is only for yourself. In 3 years when you have to change the code, you will be happy that you documented it.

If you leave the company, or have to work on another project, your co-workers will be happy to have a documented code. Undocumented code has much lower value.

And look how the real professionals do it. Here is an excerpt from the source code of *ArrayList* class by [Sun Microsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems):

```
 /**
  * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
  * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
  */
  private transient Object[] elementData;
```

Comment: Does public HelloWorld() {system.out.println("Hello World")} have less 
value than 
//prints Hello World
HelloWorld() {system.out.println("Hello World")}?

Comment: We dont talk of one line well known Hello world coede. In professional development undocumnetd code cause higher costs for the next person that work on that code. And even if it's your own code, some years after creating you loose more time thinking why and what, than the costs of documenting at time of creation fly.

Comment: It is a simple example to prove a point. Comments do not make code more valuable. If I can understand the code sans comments because it is written well then that is fine. Good method and variable names go a long way towards readable code.

Comment: good names, perfect written, super style, AND(!) well documented why things are done this way has more value than without that docu!

Comment: The question clearly is about JAVADOC. As the answer of ashes999 states, Javadoc is primarily for the people who consume your code. You're talking about COMMENTING your code and what you're saying is valid and I'm on the same path, but this doesn't count for javadoc. Javadoc isn't designed to keep your comments for yourself and your coworkers and get them out in the public for all your consumers.

Comment: @testuser to your comment: "javadoc isn't designed to keep your comments..."   Javadoc has a feature, that let you create the javadoc html for only public methods/fields. So write the private for yourself and publish only the public ones for the consumers, if there is some necessity to supress info.

Comment: @AlexWien: that's a valid point but then what's the plus in making it Javadoc comments? Why not simply keeping it as 'simple' comments? Javadoc is IMHO (a little bit, but still) more work. And for only generating the part of the public HTML, I guess it requires some extra configuration, hence, extra time spent, while you could simply add it as 'normal' comments instead.

Comment: @testuser it's far less work using javadoc: Once typing /**<Enter> the editor creates a template with all arguments of an method. And for the rest it is the same effort : writing "/**" or "//" is practically the same work. Creating the html is optional (it requires some clicks)

Comment: @AlexWien but you'd need to configure it that you won't generate the javadoc for non-public methods, hence it's more (trivial, not much, but still more) work to generate the javadoc then it is to write '//'.

Comment: @testuser, No, The option "public only" is the default option. And further it seems that you don't know javadoc, so think yourself whether it makes sense to continue this discussion.

Comment: @testuser - you say you are very knowledgeable, but you demonstrate some basic ignorance about javadoc.

Comment: @testuser of course there is verry need to comment ADDITIONALLY to javadoc. E.g within a method, to explain why you do something. or to comment the src of an algorithm with reference to the original author. However that what can be documented in javadoc should be. (Because this docu immedeatly pops up in the SW IDE and is helpfull for evry SW developper (and yourself) using the code.) And again its not more work to write "/**" than "//". If you have good reasons to hide information (e.g src of algorithm) then use standard comments.

Comment: Now your last comment is exactly what I'm trying to say. I'm not saying I know it all (in contrary to someone else here), but I'm saying you should NOT ONLY use javadoc. OP asked if he HAS TO use Javadoc. I say: you HAVE TO comment, but that doesn't HAVE TO be Javadoc. It's good practice, but I stand my point: Javadoc != Comment, comment > Javadoc only. Javadoc is a good tool and can come in handy. It's not a MUST DO though. Commenting on the other hand is. If for any reason someone comments but doesn't Javadoc things, that's still good and better than no comments at all.

Comment: @testuser, we all agree that some plain comment is better than no comments at all. We are just discussing whether Javadoc makes it even better, for both writing and reading.

Comment: I think the example from AlexWien is really bad because he has a variable with a meaningless name and tries to inject meaning using javadoc. When you have meaningless names you basically can ignore all other good practices - it won't get better

Answer (score 44):

The first question you need to ask yourself is "why write JavaDocs at all?" Who are they useful for? Who asked you to write them?

Most likely, someone (employer / professor) asked you to document some of your methods. This is generally A Good Thing, but comes with a cost: additional maintenance.

If you have a publicly accessible version of your docs (such as if you're generating them and publishing them online for end-users), it makes sense to document anything *your end users will need to know.* This includes all public classes and methods.

What about for yourself, and other developers?

My opinion is that **you shouldn't use javadocs on internal and private methods and classes.** The main reason is that javadocs primarily benefit people who consume, not maintain, your code.

On the other hand, you do need to keep notes and comments on your own code, which is often internal. In this case, I would suggest normal comments (eg. `//`) instead; it's less maintenance, and often, equally clear, with a lot less typing.

On the other hand, if a method becomes public, it can be useful to convert those comments into a true javadocs. Javadocs have the benefit of forcing you to think about (and document) every parameter, exception, and return value.

The trade-off is yours to make.

Comment: FYI, for .NET developers, Visual Studio shows these comments when you hover your mouse over a method name -- even for private methods -- so for .NET code, it makes sense to do this.

Comment: Eclipse does the same, it's a very beneficial feature.

Comment: I don't see why "//" is less maintenance that "/**". And practically using "//" is more typing, because eclipse would generate the javadoc tremplate automatically for you.

Comment: @AlexWien that's explained in my last two paragraphs. Although Eclipse generates the docs for you, it's still a lot to write (imagine a function with 4 parameters that throws 3 types of exceptions) and maintain (as you change parameters, or the exceptions that can appear change).

Comment: What about `protected` methods though (as per OP's question)? Surely you have more of a case for writing JavaDoc for those?

Comment: @Kidburla I believe that code should be self-explanatory. Docs on protected methods usually fall out-of-date, and reading the code is usually more useful.

Comment: The comments for private members is useful for contributors.

Comment: AFAIK eclipse, visual studio, netbeans and intellij can display javadoc very conveniently, so in my opinion, it's beneficial for everyone who works with your code.

Comment: @kidburla I would write javadoc comments for `protected` methods because when these are overridden they will be inherited. And also if you are developing a platform application that other developers will build upon it saves the re-writing java doc comments. If the overridden methods behaviour changes and will be used by publicly then they will need to write a revised version of the javadoc comments.

Answer (score 10):

Nope, you shouldn't write javadoc for private methods. End users don't have access to private fields or methods so there really isn't a point in providing javadoc for them. Private fields and methods are only meant for the developer. If you really need to though, feel free to write comments for non-obvious logic. You should probably write javadoc for `protected` methods because these methods are sometimes overridden and it is helpful to provide the user with some information about what the method does, or, should do.

Comment: And what about variables?

Comment: You shouldn't javadoc private fields, but you're welcome to javadoc `protected` fields because they often have some significance as to why they are `protected` as opposed to `private`. You can still provide comment lines anywhere, whether it describes a variable's purpose or logic in a method.

Comment: If you provide a comment line for a private method or field, you better instead write a javadoc, this has no disadvantage, only advatages.

Comment: @AlexWien I don't disagree with your answer, but what purpose does writing javadoc for private members serve instead of comments? Members are private to prevent the user from accessing it directly (despite reflection). If you javadoc private members, aren't you making it easier for the end user to reverse engineer the program?

Comment: writing javadoc does not mean presenting it to the end user. javadoc for a private mthod gives a structuire how to (internally) comment. It demands commenting all parameters and The return value. This is a fast template, and speeds up your documenting time. To protect for reverse engineering, you have to obfuscate, and keep the public interface. Further eclipse shows a nice mouse pop over docu for a (private) method of it is javadoced

Comment: @AlexWien totally agree, it's very nice to be able to hover over a variable (whether it's private or not) and get a quick summary of what it's supposed to be doing

Comment: Have to respectfully disagree ~ The JDK authors do it so It's probably a good practice to follow... check out DualPivotQuickSort as an example.

Comment: So no maintenance in mind. Sure, if you write perfect code it may apply.

With the same attitude you can delete the source after build.

Comment: @JoshM you could run javadoc once with -private for internal documentation, and again without that option for public documentation.

Comment: We document everything for the simple reason that it helps co-developers. We have internal docs built with `-private` and customer docs built with `-protected` (the default).

Answer (score 6):

You often hear the general recommendation that, in the best case, comments should simply not be *necessary* at all. But concerning JavaDoc, they play an important role not only for the developer, but also for the user of the library.

Additionally, writing JavaDoc comments may be more useful for you (especially for a beginner) than for anyone else: When you find it hard to describe what a variable is or what a method does with a single `/** One-line-JavaDoc comment */`, then you'll automatically re-think what you have done there.

When generating JavaDocs, you may choose whether you want to generate them only for the `public` and `protected` parts of the API, or also for default- or `private` elements.

However, you should in any case document `protected` methods: May someone who extends the class only *call* this method, or is he also allowed to override this method? If so, are there any pre- and postconditions that he should know about? Should he call `super.theMethod()` in the overridden version? (BTW: If he's not allowed to override the method, then it should be `final`, but documented anyhow)

BTW: I personally comment *everything*, but know that most people think it's not necessary or even a bad style, especially for "trivial" things

```
/**
 * The number of elements in this set
 */
private final int numberOfElements;
```

I think it does not harm, but helps in many cases. Maybe, regarding `private` parts, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: "comments should simply not be *necessary* at all" True, but documentation isn’t comments. Comments are in-method prose that helps someone reading the source code to understand when they need to change something. Documentation is for consumers of code. This obviously applies to `public` and `protected` stuff, but also to package-private and even `private` stuff. Unless it’s a one-man project, documentation helps your colleagues use the methods you wrote correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to javadoc anything, but it's very helpful to.  More javadocs are never a bad thing.

Per your question, if you use the javadoc documentation compiler, javadocs will be compiled for protected methods, but not private methods.  There's no reason they can't still be used as code comments, though.

Comment: „Information is a difference that makes a difference“. JavaDoc should only be written if it expresses something the plain code/API cannot.

Comment: "More javadocs are never a bad thing" That’s not exactly true. Documentation is a form of repetition. Keeping documentation up-to-date is work and the less documentation there is, and the more important the docs that exist are, the higher is the likelihood that code changes that require doc changes are actually followed up by doc changes.